# Reusing interfaces throughout your application

Tags: c++, interface, modularity

I am currently busy refactoring big parts in my application.  The main purpose is to remove as much as possible dependencies between the different modules.  I now stumble on the following problem:

In my application I have a GUI module that has defined an interface IDataProvider.  The interface needs to be implemented by the application and is used to 'provide data' to the GUI module.  E.g. a data grid can be given this IDataProvider and use it to loop over all the instances that should be shown in the data grid, and getting their data.

Now have another module (in fact quite some more modules) that all need something similar (like a reporting module, a database integration module, a mathematical solver module, ...).  At this moment I can see 2 things I can do:

- I could move IDataProvider from the GUI layer to a much lower-level layer and reuse this same interface in all the other modules.

  - This has the advantage that it becomes easier for the application to use all the modules (it only has to implement a data provider once).
  - The disadvantage is that I introduce a dependency between the modules and the central IDataProvider.  If someone starts to extend IDataProvider with additional methods needed for one module, it also starts to pollute the other modules.
- The other alternative is to give every module its own data provider, and force the application to implement all of them if it wants to use all the modules.

  - The advantage is that the modules are not dependent on a common part
  - The disadvantage is that I end up with IGridDataProvider, IReportDataProvider, IDatabaseDataProvider, ISolverDataProvider.

What's the best approach to use?  Is it acceptible to make all modules dependent on the same common interface if they require [almost or completely] the same kind of interface?

If I use the same IDataProvider interface, can this give nasty problems in the future (which I am not aware of at this moment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do an intermediate implementation? Have some class implement recurring parts of `IDataProvider` (as in the 1st case) in a factored-out library (or other layer). Also, everyone is required to "implement" their own `IDataProvider` (as in the 2nd case). Then, you can re-use your `IDataProvider` implementation all over the place and add specific methods in custom classes by creating a derived class...

I.e.:

```
    // Common module.
class BasicDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
public:
    // common overrides...
};

    // For modules requiring no specific methods...
typedef BasicDataProvider ReportDataProvider;

    // Database module requires "special" handling.
class DatabaseDataProvider : BasicDataProvider
{
public:
    // custom overrides...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that additional methods would be applied to an interface you can use an Adaptor pattern.  That is:

```
class myFoo{
public:
    Bar getBar() =0;
}
```

and in the other module:

```
class myBaz{
public:
    Bar getBar() =0;
}
```

Then to use one with the other:

```
class MyAdaptor: public myBaz{
public:
    MyAdaptor(myFoo *_input){
        m_Foo = _input;
    }

    Bar getBar(){ return m_Foo->getBar(); }

private:
    myFoo* m_Foo;
}
```

That way you implement everything in your `myBaz` interface and only need to supply the glue in one place.  The `myFoo` can have as many additional methods added to it as they want, the rest of your application need not know or care about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to the disadvantage you cite for moving IDataProvider to a lower-level layer.

A module that wants an extended interface could put those extensions in its own sub-interface of IDataProvider. You could encourage this by pro-actively creating those sub-interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind having multiple module depending on one interface even if it doesn't use all of the methods the interface publishes. You could also think more in a meaning for part of the interface instead of for what module is it intended. Most of the module you mention only need read access. So you could separate in this way and have another for write, etc.

The data layer doesn't need to know what the data is used for(which is the job of the presentation layer). It only needs to know how to return it and how to modify it.

Moreover, there's absolutely no problem into moving the data provider(which could also be labeled as a controller) to a lower level because it's probably already implementing some business logic(like data consistency) which has nothing to do with the UI.